# Calculation in Info-path Repetitive section

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, infopath

Using SharePoint Online with InfoPath 2013

I have a field named "Marks" in a repetitive section.

I want that when user add repetitive section and put the data in Marks field, a condition will apply that the total of all "Marks" field figures will be <=100.  if user is adding a no. that make the total more then 100 then he/she will not be able to enter the data.

More then 50 users will going to use this form and I want that this condition will consider the total of each user separately.

Pls suggest if this is achievable ? if yes then how !

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is achievable.

Try this:

1. Create a *Total Marks* field. Set this value using the formula `sum(Marks)`
2. Create a button(Submit). This button will be disabled when Total Marks field is > 100. Create a formatting rule that with condition `Total Marks > 100`, disable the button. You can also put an error message saying "change the value, the total cannot be more than 100".